# Page reload if react-router-dom doesn't match any route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

We are working in a project which is written in dotnet with Razor views (Pure Backend stack). Our plan to move every view to `React` using `react-router-dom` to handle routing in the client and server.

What we have in mind is to move page by page not to do a big bang because the project is already in production.

When I setup `react-router-dom` looks like every page is handled on the client and there is no full page reload if the route is not within the routes that `Router` handles.

**Client Router**

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from 'history'

const history: History = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl })

<Router history={history}>
  ...(routes and page layout)
</Router>
```

**Server Router**

```
<StaticRouter
 basename={basename}
 context={routerContext}
 location={params.location.path}
>
   ...(routes and page layout)
</StaticRouter>
```

Is there any way to make the router work in this way:

- If the route is within the ones handled by `react-router-dom`, then do client side transition
- If the router is not within the ones handled by `react-router-dom` (which means it's still handled by dotnet backend), make a full page reload.

Let me know if you need more information.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `NoMatch` component for * route at the end of your `Router`

```
<Route component={NoMatch} />
```

and define your `NoMatch` component like below

```
function NoMatch() {
    window.location.reload();
    return null;
}
```

Also, your routes should be within a `<Switch>` because otherwise `NoMatch` will execute as well as your route and this will cause and endless loop.
See documentation for more details: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: I tried your solution, with a `typeof window !== 'undefined'` to check if I'm in the server or client. But it keeps me on a reload loop. Not sure this works properly.

Comment: In that case, you should check your server config

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with the server configuration as both server and client are using the same set of routes. I updated the question with the server router. You can have a look. thanks

Comment: As per documentation: "Routes without a path always match". So it will keep entering in that component (that's why I have a endless loop) even if the route matches.

Comment: @AlejandroGarciaAnglada Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue with rails views

Comment: There is some issue with this implementation, while the reload thing works, but pressing back button does not change the url and page remains same

Answer (score 0):

Luckily we have [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md) prop to help, which provides an `action` param that can indicate whether the user navigated from another route or started on the current route directly.

So this is how I solved the reload-loop issue:

```js
/**
 * Handles Legacy/SSR pages, reloads the page when the location changes
 *
 * @param {object} props Props
 * @param {object} props.location Location object
 * @param {object} props.history  History object
 */
const LegacyRoute = ( { location, history } ) => {
    useEffect( () => {
        // Reload the page if the location change ( and not on first load )
        if ( history.action === 'PUSH' ) {
            window.location.reload();
        }

        return () => {
            // Reload the page if we navigate away to another route
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, [ location.pathname ] );

    return null;
}
```

Then you define the route as:

```js
<Route component={ LegacyRoute } />
```